# How to find a 10% discount of all elements in a JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

How do I find the discounted price of all the elements? The discount should be 10%

Here is what I have attempted:

```
    var arr = [299.99, 399.99, 599.99, 799.99]
    arr.forEach((value, index) => {
    arr[index] * (10/100)

});
```

Comment: What is the issue here? Atleast ask the question properly. Please read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: In a forEach loop you don't need to write `arr[index]`, but only `value`. If you want the discount price you need to multiply by (1 - discount_percentage / 100) so in your case .9

Answer (score 2):

Map it

```
  var discount = arr.map(el => el * 0.9);
```

If you want 2 decimals use `toFixed(2)`

```
  var discount = arr.map(el => (el * 0.9).toFixed(2));
```

The values will convert to string. So parse it back

```
   var discount = arr.map(el => parseFloat((el * 0.9).toFixed(2)));
```

Answer (score 0):

When working with money you should use pennies to avoid loss of precision errors.

The following uses `Array#Map` to calculate the discounted price, and then `Number#toFixed` to round it to the nearest penny. If this is for production code, then you need to make absolutely sure that this type of rounding is permitted.

```js
var arr = [299.99, 399.99, 599.99, 799.99]
const discount = (arr) => arr.map((el) => (el - el * (10/100)).toFixed(2))
console.log(discount(arr))
```